# How to hide URI with Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem and I need to hide a segment of the URL, for example:

```
example.com/folder/example.php/folder1/folder2/example2
```

I need to remove or hide the part of `/folder1/folder2/exaample`

and to have `example.com/folder/exaple.php`

Thanks

**NOTE: The problem is that as I access the files the URIs are accumulating and I can not do that**

Comment: you may want to do this in your routing rather than use jquery to change the url in the browser

Comment: That something you do in the PHP and webserver part, not jQuery.

Comment: @Ibu we think the same thing :)

Comment: You cannot do it with Javascript or jQuery but you can work with .htaccess file or use a router class to achive what you want.